# NSDictionary initWithObjectsAndKeys from macro fails

Tags: ios, macros, nsdictionary

Im trying to init a NSDictionary with keys and values both strings, i want to init from a defined macro:

```
#define _FILETYPES @".c", @"c", @".h", @"c",".cpp", @"cpp", @".d", @"d", @".hs", @"haskell", @".lua", @"lua", @".ml", @"ocaml", @".mli", @"ocaml", @".php", @"php", @".pl", @"perl", @".py", @"python", @".rb", @"ruby", @".scm", @"scheme", @".ss", @"scheme", @".tcl", @"tcl", nil


#define _LANGS @"c", @"C", @"cpp", @"C++", @"d", @"D", @"haskell", @"Haskell", @"lua", @"Lua", @"ocaml", @"OCaml", @"php", @"PHP", @"perl", @"Perl", @"python", @"Python", @"ruby", @"Ruby", @"scheme", @"Scheme", @"tcl", @"Tcl", nil

self.languages = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:_LANGS];
self.filetypes = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:_FILETYPES];
```

Can you tell me why this is not working. I have been initiating arrays similarly before...
The problem is that as soon as i the alloc lines are reached the code throws an EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: It works, actually :)

Comment: the key c was used two times in _FILETYPES

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forget @ before ".cpp" and "perl"..

Comment: Good catch! - (In the code of the question it is missing only before ".cpp")